# Invert object using only pure functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, persistence, immutability

Assume you have an object like this:

```
{
  a: [1,2,3],
  b: [2],
  c: [1,4]
}
```

and you need to convert it to:

```
{
  1: ['a', 'c'],
  2: ['a', 'b'],
  3: ['a'],
  4: ['c']
}
```

It's simple to do this using imperative way and mutable data structures:

```
function convert (obj) {
  var key, values
    , result = {};

  for (key in obj) {
    values = obj[key];
    values.forEach(function (value) {
      result[value] = result[value] || []; // bad — mutability :(
      result[value].push(key); // bad — mutability :(
    });
  }

  return result;
}
```

But is there any way of doing this by using only pure functions and without using any assignments?
Usage of some library for functional programming is allowed.

Comment: You can make the resulting data structure immutable *after* you've finished building it up. I don't understand why it is important to have it be immutable during processing - if there *was* some combination of built-in JS functions that did this I imagine they would use mutable data structures and assignments under the covers.

Comment: @nnnnnn Of course, lower level of programming would use mutability while constructing the result. But I'm looking for a way to abstract from this. Thank you for your opinion.

Comment: @Girafa But is there any way of doing this by using only pure functions and without using any assignments?  `No, you can't`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, its a pure data transformation, so you can definitely do it without using mutable variables. Let's do it in Haskell, which gives us a static guarantee that there is no explicit mutation. We start with an example:

```
d :: [(Char, [Integer])]
d = [('a', [1,2,3]), ('b', [2]), ('c', [1,4])]
```

Ok, so what are the keys of the new structure? They're the unique elements of the first structure:

```
> import Data.List
> let keys = sort . nub . concatMap snd $ d
[1,2,3,4]
```

and then we need to know in which column each value appeared. So pair each value with its key:

```
> let pairs = concatMap (\(k,v) -> map (,k) v) d
[(1,'a'),(2,'a'),(3,'a'),(2,'b'),(1,'c'),(4,'c')]
```

Now we can build the result:

```
 > [ (k, map snd . filter ((== k) . fst) $ pairs ) | k <- keys ]
 [(1,"ac"),(2,"ab"),(3,"a"),(4,"c")]
```

In its full glory:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

import Data.List

rotate d = [ (k, map snd . filter ((== k) . fst) $ pairs ) | k <- keys ]
    where
        keys  = sort . nub . concatMap snd $ d
        pairs = concatMap (\(k,v) -> map (,k) v) d
```

E.g.

```
*A> rotate [('a', [1,2,3]), ('b', [2]), ('c', [1,4])]
[(1,"ac"),(2,"ab"),(3,"a"),(4,"c")]
```

Or a point-free version with no named intermediate structures:

```
rotate2  = map (\x -> (head (map fst x), map snd x))
         . groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
         . sortBy (comparing fst)
         . concatMap (\(k,v) -> map (,k) v)
```

Good little interview question :)

Comment: Oh, thank you! Despite the fact that this in not javascript, the algorithm is clear here.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to do this using [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/) library:

```
compose(
  reduce(function(acc, key) {
    return assoc(key, filter(compose(contains(key), propOf(src)), keys(src)), acc);
  }, {}),
  uniq,
  flatten,
  values
)(src)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given an associative data structure like Haskell's `Data.Map`, I would write this by creating, for each pair `(v, ks) :: (String, [Int])`, several maps containing just `k |-> [v]` (i.e. each key is mapped to a singleton list containing the only value) and then merge them.

Keeping with Haskell syntax, that would get you something like

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map

insideOut :: (Ord k) => [(v, [k])] -> [(k, [v])]
insideOut vks = Map.toList . Map.unionsWith (++) $
                [ Map.singleton k [v] | (v, ks) <- vks, k <- ks]
```